# PowerMockito Verify times always passes

Tags: java, junit, mockito

I am trying to use `Powermockiti.verify(mockObj, times(1))` to ascertain a static void method has been called once but even if I change the value of `times()` to any other number it still passes.

// Class to be tested:

```
package nl.naturalis.nba.etl;

public class Person { 
  public static void someVoidMethod() {
    System.out.println("someVoidMethod Called");
  }
}
```

// Test Class:

/**
 * 
 */

```
package com.test.using.mockito

import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.mockito.Mockito;
import org.powermock.core.classloader.annotations.PowerMockIgnore;
import org.powermock.core.classloader.annotations.PrepareForTest;
import org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.times;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.never;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.atMost;
import org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito;

@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(Person.class)
@PowerMockIgnore("javax.management.*")
@SuppressWarnings({"static-method"})
public class PersonTest {

  /**
   * @throws java.lang.Exception
   */
  @Before
  public void setUp() throws Exception {}

  /**
   * @throws java.lang.Exception
   */
  @After
  public void tearDown() throws Exception {}

  /**
   * Test method for {@link nl.naturalis.nba.etl.Person#someVoidMethod()}.
   */
  @Test
  public void testSomeVoidMethod() {

/*    Person person = Mockito.mock(Person.class);

    person.someVoidMethod();    
    Mockito.verify(person, times(1));
    person.someVoidMethod();*/

   PowerMockito.mock(Person.class);
   Person.someVoidMethod();
   PowerMockito.verifyStatic(Person.class,times(6));
   Person.someVoidMethod();

  }
}
```

Now if even if I change the value of times to 2 or any higher value it still passes.

no matter what value I put in the `Mockito.times()` it always passes

```
   Person.someVoidMethod();
   PowerMockito.verifyStatic(Person.class,times(6));
   Person.someVoidMethod();
```

I have also tries using `VerificationModeFactory.times(6)` instead of `Mockito.times(6)` but really doesn't make any difference.

Comment: Can you give a complete example?  Is `someVoidMethod` perhaps a *static* method, in which case it's never actually going through the mock proxies?  Most IDEs would warn you if you access a static method via an instance.

Comment: Hi Mark, Its not a static method just a public void someVoidMethod{ ..some logic ..}. Since you have mentioned i have changed the method to static and tried to use PowerMockito.verifyStatic() as well as shown below :  `PowerMockito.mock(ClassForTest.class);
    ClassForTest.someVoidMethod(testObj);
    PowerMockito.verifyStatic(ClassForTest.class, times(5));` But still it passes the test even though its been called only once.

Comment: Well it works for me just dandy, though I get the same results as you if it is static.  I wasn't saying it should be static, just trying to guess what the issue might be since you haven't given a complete example.

Comment: In your test ..does it fail if you change the verify number to say 10 ?

Comment: I tried it with an own example and it worked. Could you provide us with more informations about your code?

Comment: @JoeRodreques: It works exactly as you'd expect.  If I have 1 call and expect 5, it fails.  If I have no calls, it fails.  If I expect 5 and call it 5 times, it passes.  I think it's likely there's a lot you're not telling us.  Strip the issue down to the simplest reproducible example, by doing so you'll probably even find the problem.

Comment: Make a little `Person` class or so and add a method `public void test()` then create a `PersonTest` class. There you do `Person mockPerson = mock(Person.class)` and then `mockPerson.test()` followed by `verify(mockPerson, times(1)).test()` It should pass and not fail.

Comment: Questionare , I will do what you have mentioned and let you know the result. But the test method looks exactly the way i have mentioned above. I have converted the someVoidMethod() to static now it looks like this :  `public static void someVoidMethod(Object2 obj) 
 {
  //Just system.out printing the object value...
 }`  And I m using Powermockito instead of Mockito as below `PowerMockito.mock(ClassForTest.class); ClassForTest.someVoidMethod(testObj); PowerMockito.verifyStatic(ClassForTest.class, times(5));` .It still passes :(

Comment: @JoeRodreques: You gotta take a step back, you're fumbling a bit.  Forget the static and PowerMock stuff, I mentioned static methods because with the details you gave that's the only way I could think of that you'd get the results you were getting.  Making it static wasn't meant to be a solution (read what I actually wrote)

Comment: Did you run the right test? I'm sure that you have ran other tests rather than this one. good luck...

Comment: As for me the test tests nothing. You mocked the `ClassForTest` and try to test dummy method. Note, your real production code is not invoked. The fact you test how does Mock framework works. Probably you need to call the real `someVoidMethod` method and verify the changed state of the object if any or verify the called inside other methods if any.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stupid Me.. I didnt notice that I was using PowerMockito.mock() instead of PowerMockito.mockStatic(). Now it works correctly :

```
  @Test
  public void testSomeVoidMethod() {

   PowerMockito.mockStatic(Person.class);

   Person.someVoidMethod();
   PowerMockito.verifyStatic(Person.class,Mockito.times(6));
   Person.someVoidMethod();


  }

}
```

Comment: Why `times(6)`? You only call it once.

Comment: I was trying to show that it works how it suppose to : so for times(1) it passes and times(6) it fails.

Answer (score 0):

Without more details I'd say the likely explanation is that `someVoidMethod` is a static method.  If it is, most IDEs would give you warnings on the lines where you access it via an instance.

Mockito works by creating dynamic proxies based on a class you pass in.  The methods on your object are replaced with methods which perform verifications, setup, etc.  When you call a static method, however, it doesn't go through an instance.  The compiler replaces any call that looks like this:

```
ClassForTest classForTest = mock(ClassForTest.class);
verify(classForTest).someVoidMethod("foo");
```

Into this:

```
ClassForTest classForTest = mock(ClassForTest.class);
verify(classForTest);
ClassForTest.someVoidMethod("foo");
```

Therefore bypassing Mockito code entirely (including the verification).

Some mocking libraries, like PowerMock, allow you to replace static methods.  However, Mockito does not because in most cases it would encourage bad design: https://github.com/mockito/mockito/issues/1013.

Comment: Hi @Mark Peters, as suggested by TheQuestioner I created a simple person class with a void method in my package and a corresponding test class and used the Mockito.verify(mockobj, times(2)) after i called the method on the mock object but it passes the test where it should have failed. I want to paste the whole code here but i m sure how/where? in the comments or update the original post?

Comment: Even if i use Mockito.verify(person, never()); it passes. :-/

Comment: @JoeRodreques: You can edit your question with the relevant details.  But posting the "whole code" doesn't seem like a good idea unless it's very small, you need to do your duty and [post a minimal, complete, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  This is an important aspect of debugging even aside from using it to get help.

Comment: thanks for the tip. This actually works now when i call on the  `Person.someVoidMethod();` before and after i call `Mockito.verify(person, times(1));` which i didnt do earlier. But for my understanding, now if i udpate the someVoidMethod to static it doenst work. Neither with Mockitio.verify() not with PowerMockito.verifyStatic(). Please see the code i updated above.